# merging buffers and interleaving the while recording from a microphone

Tags: javascript, arrays, buffer, wav

I have done some research on how to record from a microphone and save the file.I found an example but not all functions explained well.If someone can explain to me what does these two functions exactly do?

```
function mergeBuffers(channelBuffer, recordingLength){
var result = new Float32Array(recordingLength);
var offset = 0;
var lng = channelBuffer.length;
for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++){
var buffer = channelBuffer[i];
result.set(buffer, offset);
offset += buffer.length;
}
    return result;
   }
```

and this is the second function:

```
function interleave(leftChannel, rightChannel){
var length = leftChannel.length + rightChannel.length;
var result = new Float32Array(length);

var inputIndex = 0;

for (var index = 0; index < length; ){
 result[index++] = leftChannel[inputIndex];
 result[index++] = rightChannel[inputIndex];
 inputIndex++;
}
return result;
}
```

I have understood so far that the sound obtained from the source (microphone) is saved in a buffer in the type of float array.Two buffers are saved,leftChannel and rightChannel resembling both speakers(left and right)
here is the link of the example I'm talking about: http://typedarray.org/from-microphone-to-wav-with-getusermedia-and-web-audio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names and sources of both functions are quite self-explanatory IMHO:

- `mergeBuffers` merges several buffers into one by concatenating them. `channelBuffer` is an array containing several buffers, and you get a single buffer with all these buffers concatenated.
- `interleave` takes two buffers, and returns a single buffer with alternating left and right channel values, which is a pretty standard representation of stereo sound.

Comment: I do understand that but why do I merge buffers and why do I interleave a buffer??

Comment: It's all explained in the article you linked to. The `onaudioprocess` handler is called repeatedly while recorded. Each time it is called, it receives a buffer for each channel (containing the data since the start of the recording the first time, then the data since the last call thereafter). The example code given saves these buffers, which are then merged (left and right separately) and interleaved (because that's how a WAV file is supposed to have the channels).

Comment: i want to edit the file download instead of downloading automatically when stop recording, i want a link to be shown so that when user clicks the link the record will open.how can that be done?if you can help please

Comment: That's beyond the scope of your original question, and what do you mean by "edit"? If you just want a to separate the end of the recording from saving the file, just remove the `click` creation and dispatch, and instead add the `link` that was created to your page wherever you want to.